# call class with in a class from other java program

Tags: java

If there are two classes in a java program and we have another java program how can we use the function of 2nd class of first java program to 2nd java program e.g
One java program

```
Public class A
{
Public class B
{
void a();
void b();
}
}
```

Second java program
    Public class C
    {
    i want to call void a() and void b() here 
    }

Comment: your question is vague. What is the objective ?   From class C you want to use class B's methods ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by inheritance.

```
public class C extends B {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    C foo = new C();
    foo.a();
    foo.b();    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, you would need to create an instance of `B`. Let's call this instance `bTest`. You could then call these methods like this:

```
B bTest = new B();
bTest.a();
bTest.b();
```

Now, if you made `a()` and `b()` static methods, you would call them using the name of the class they are in rather than using an instance of it, as such:

```
B.a();
B.b();
```

Keep in mind that you will have to import `B` if it is not in the same package as `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your inner class is not static one you have to create an object of A first and then create object of B.

```
    A a = new A();
    A.B b = a.new B();
    b.a();
    b.b();
```